# Hide content in local html doc if browser is not connected to internet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML file which displays simple static content but I would like to display a number of youtube videos in `iframes` on this document, and I do know how to do this. 
What I want is to prevent these from loading ( and just display the static content ) if the browser is not connected to the internet. Is there any way to do this.
I can use HTML, CSS, Javascript or jQuery

Comment: Do an XHR request to something and see whether is succeeds.

Comment: Even better you should do the same but inverted, show static content - and change it to videos if the xhr succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [online/offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events) and the [`navigator.onLine` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine). If those are not available, you can only try to load the content and listen for errors (and view them only if loaded correctly).

Comment: @Diodeus: Isn't a timeout an error as well?

Comment: Depends on what you're implementing. For example, I don't think you get an error with an onload event for an Iframe in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.onLine returns true for active network connection and false for offline!